# Javascript input type=file is there any way to define target directory?

Tags: javascript

[EDIT] I'm working on a web UI with the following attributes:

1. The web server runs locally on the user's machine
2. The location of the csv files in question are static, and never change
3. The UI uses javascript to communicate with a Java REST controller, which then handles the heavy lifting for the file reading/editing/writing

In the UI itself the user selects a csv file, then that file gets loaded into the UI for viewing, editing, etc. I wanted to pass the path to a REST controller, then have the receiving Java application read the file, etc. but it appears you can't get the path using input type file for security reasons. For my purposes though this would work just as well if I can limit the directory access since the files will always be local and always be located in the same place. Basically, the user can select csv files from one of several directories:

.../CSVType1/*.csv

.../CSVType2/*.csv

.../CSVType3/*.csv

So if the current type being edited is CSVType1 I'm trying to prevent the user from accessing the other directories in order to prevent them from trying to load the wrong type. If the path could be accessed I could do a quick check and throw up an alert if they're in the wrong directory, but limiting access would work fine too. Right now I've got it so that it only accepts csv files:

```
<input type="file" accept=".csv" ng-model="CsvFileInfo.selectedFilename" id="csvFile" style="display:none" />
```

But is there a way to say 'only accept csv files within this directory and its subdirectories'?

Comment: You can't. But you can load them without JAVA with HTML5 filereader.

Comment: @Phix — That's the point they were making.

Comment: @Phix ... so? Has nothing to do with my comment. Author asks about WEB UI -> JAVA solution and tags it as JAVASCRIPT. My comment still applies.

Comment: A typical web app would have the server and client running on completely different computers where the server would not be able to access the file system of the client at all. Either you are going to trip over that really soon or you have a highly atypical setup (e.g. an intranet) that should be explained in the question.

Comment: @Quentin so how can it be the case when op selects a file from local machine? My comment still applies the situation described by op. There is no way to get a real file path from `input[type="file"]`... if he needs to use the file in JAVA, he needs to load it first and pass it as blob or something.

Comment: Since you can't rely on user's local directory structure , user needs to select  directory in the UI. Then you need rules per those directories and prevent the file if it doesn't validate.

Comment: Okay, I can see I wasn't clear enough - I'm new to javascript so bear with me please. I added more details into the original question. This is basically an HTML UI with Javascript underneath, which then passes data to a REST controller where I do most of the file manipulation in Java. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @FlashThunder I'm totally willing to concede that I may not be able to have the receiving Java component do the actual reading and writing. Do you know if I read the data in on the javascript end and pass the file *contents* to the REST controller rather than the file *path*, when the controller hands back the edited text, does the javascript component know internally where to write the edited file? I get that it won't give me the path for security reasons, but does it still know the path internally?

Comment: @jamesknapp oh so it is impossible to do... you need to select a file in JAVA then. But that also may be blocked because of security reasons. To be honest I personally hate JAVA. Getting a real path from `input[type="file"]` is not possible in any way.